# Using /etc/environment.d/*.conf to set global environment for all users

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

Is `/etc/environment.d/*.conf` a valid place to put environment config on Ubuntu 18.04 for all users?

I've tried a file with the following contents:

```
BRAD_TEST=true
```

However, after logging in and running `env`, this variable does not appear to be set in the environment.  Even after a reboot, it wasn't there.

Two questions:

- Is this feature of systemd enabled in Ubuntu 18.04?
- Does this feature allow setting environment for all users, or is it intended for another purpose?

Comment: remember when we used to just put everything in /etc/rc.local? oh the good ol days

Comment: I don't know about `/etc/environment.d` but that is done in `/etc/environment` file!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I'm asking about environment.d specifically. I have a handful of files I would like to put there. If it works, it will help me keep some things organized a bit better than my current setup.

Comment: Does it exists as of todays Ubuntus? I am pretty young to Linux but all of my current trainings has not talk about any such folder.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen That's sort of the question.  :-)  It's documented as such:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/environment.d.5.html

Comment: Thank you for that link now I know better and if I may as did you name the file as directed in that man page? I will test it out now!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, I named the file `/etc/environment.d/test.conf`.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I don't know if that feature is enabled on Ubuntu. But an alternative, to organize your system variables better is the `/etc/profile.d` folder whose `*.sh` files are sourced at session startup. If you go that route, please note that new environment variables need to be explicitly `export`ed.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it is but I had to create that folder and a reboot produced the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Ok after rebooting my system today I got it to work but I followed the recommended naming style for such files and this `60-foo.conf` is the name I gave to the file and I also had to create that folder and it was called `environment.d` and of course it was placed in the `/etc` folder.

This is the content of that file:

```
FOO_DEBUG=force-software-gl,log-verbose
```

After the reboot doing `echo $FOO_DEBUG` produced the contents of that file:

```
force-software-gl,log-verbose
```

Note several things here:

- Filename follows convention as found in the [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/environment.d.5.html)

Comment: Interesting!  So, to clarify, `foo.conf` is no good, but `60-foo.conf` is?  I might have to submit a pull request for the documentation.  :-)  I'll try this out today, thanks for digging into it!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Just wondering about your statement that values are comma separated. Isn't that determined by the applications which use those variables? It appears to me as if the value in your example simply is the string `"force-software-gl,log-verbose"`, and if the intention is to denote a list, the string needs to be split. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That came from the man page in the link OP provided. That's in the case that the values are more than one but if one of course it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks again. My interpretation is that comma as separator is not part of the spec., but just an example. Please note that colon is used as the separator for list values in several other environment variables.

Comment: I best remove that as it place no special role but as normally used.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Is it possible you got this working in some other way, or by doing something in addition to renaming the file?  I've tried the exact file name and contents you've posted here, but with no luck.  I'm also curious what the permissions are for your file and directory... perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: @brad sorry I saw your response late. I don't remember doing anything. I even try reloading systemd but only after restarting did it work. But will check when not on mobile.

Comment: note, I believe running `systemctl daemon-reload` (or with the `--user` flag if we are talking about `.config/environment.d/`) then logging out and in is sufficient to read from the new files